# Can't request balance using RPC

Tags: rpc

I'm trying using C#.
Getting the following error message:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": -32700,
    "message": "Parse error"
},
"id": 0,
"jsonrpc": ""
```

}

Basically doing the following, which *should* work.
Could anyone shed some light? Been looking at some examples, but can't find the issue.

```
var values = new NameValueCollection();
values["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
values["id"] = "0";
values["method"] = "getbalance";
```

Comment: I see some info in the logs:

`2016-Oct-02 18:38:05.922851 [RPC0]Failed to parse json, what: Wrong JSON charact
er at: jsonrpc=2.0&id=0&method=getbalance`

Answer (score 4):

Here's the curl command I use:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getbalance","id":"test"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Your JSON seems to be formatted entirely incorrectly, as name=value pairs, so check the library you're using to produce the JSON.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, I tried with that and it turns out C# was not doing what I wanted.
Worked with "client.UploadData" instead of "client.UploadValues".